# Alpine JS change data from within a js function

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, alpine.js

I'm trying to call a function `openBag();` from a larger js file once it has finished loading a product into the bag.

I have this code where `changeData` keeps coming back as undefined.

Is this the correct approach? Do I have something wrong, or should I approach this in a different way?

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
window.Alpine = Alpine

window.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('setData', () => ({
        showDrawer:false, drawerTab:'', showNav:false, showBack:false, showMenu:false, showFilters:false, isMobile:(window.innerWidth < 480) ? true : false
    }))
})

Alpine.start()

window.openBag = function() {
    const changeData = Alpine.data('setData');
    if (changeData) {
        changeData.showDrawer = true,
        changeData.drawerTab = 'bag'
    } else {
        console.log(changeData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set data again using `Alpine.data`, there is no way to get the data.

Comment: Thanks @Onkar, I tried that with the below but it doesn't change the values when it is called.

Is this what you meant? 

'''
window.openBag = function() {
   Alpine.data('setData', () => ({
        showDrawer:true, 
        drawerTab:'bag'
    }))
}
'''

Comment: If you are asking whether your solution is correct, you need to specify very precisely what your intention is, to make sure that the answer will not need to be opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Alpine.data()` you can define a component, it's not for accessing the component's properties. What you are looking for is an event listener on the component that can act if the `openBag` event is dispatched form the other JS function, like:

```
const openBagEvent = new Event("openBag");

// Dispatch the event on some element (can be the body)
element.dispatchEvent(openBagEvent);
```

And at the Alpine.js component we create an event listener with [`x-on`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#custom-events) shortcut:

```
<div x-data="setData" @open_bag.window.camel="showDrawer = true; drawerTab = 'bag'">
...
</div>
```

If the component receives the `openBag` custom event, then it will mutate some of its properties.